# Is there any framework that will make jquery do the right thing on mousevents for ios?

Tags: ios, jquery

When working with mouse events with jquery and ios, one needs to add additional event types such as `touchstart` and `touchend` to every traditional `mousedown`, `mouseup`, etc, mouse binding. On top of that for `touchmove`, additional boilerplate code is needed to get the right eventObject values.

i.e.:

```
e.preventDefault();
var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
```

Is there any framework I could use to allow me to use only the traditional desktop mous events, and have jquery do the right thing in ios safari?

Comment: I don't think you can map like that because a touch event is different than mouse. For example, hovering effect and touch effect could be different, you can code your functionality in such a way so you can .trigger('mouseEventsHere') on touch events

Comment: Does jQuery Mobile help at all in this?

Comment: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch